# Issue with SQLite-net-pcl with MvvmCross

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, service, mvvmcross

I'm trying to use SQlite-net-pcl to store some data.
As I read from different posts, I have to create an interface service on my main project and then implementing from that service on my Android and iOS projects.
The issue happens when I try to implement the interface on the Android or iOS project:

```
namespace DemoApplication.iOS
{
   public class LocalFileHelperService : ILocalFileHelperService
   {

   }
 }
```

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ILocalFileHelperService'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

But when I try to add the reference:

```
using DemoApplication.Services;
```

I get the following error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'DemoApplication' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Am I doing anything wrong? I remember that using another framework that was the correct form to implement services in Android and iOS platforms, but now in MvvmCross seems that is made different.

Does anyone knows how is the correct form to do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I attach the interface definition.

```
namespace DemoApplication.Services
{
    public interface ILocalFileHelperService
    {
        string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your iOS project have a reference to the shared project containing ILocalFileHelperService?

Comment: Your approach seems correct. Can you confirm that your `ILocalFileHelperService` existing in the main core project, and that it is public access modifier type? Additionally, if you do a rebuild on your main project does the interface perhaps then show up in your platform projects?

Comment: @Jason yes it has.Android and IOS Project both have the reference to the DemoApplication Project (which is where I have the public interface created).

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I edited the post with the Interface definition.
What do you refer when you say platform Project?

Comment: @flaurens I was just curious if you where to compile the main project which has your interface if after compile you where to then be able to access your interface in your Android or iOS project (i.e. platform projects).

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I tried but I'm getting the same error. Do you know if maybe I have to register the interface in the AppBase?

Comment: Hmm, @flaurens, perhaps try restarting Visual Studio. The issue you are having seems to be a tooling issue. You will have to register your interface but as you are creating platform specific implementations you would have to register it in each platform. However, that would not explain the behaviour you are seeing, as registration is required for runtime not compile time.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r Restarting VisulStudio, the Project gets me correctly the referece. Thank you very much.
Do you know how I have to register the Interfece or beeing an mvvmcros Project it's not necessary?

Comment: Glad it worked. Out of interest, had you just created your main (Core) project and was it a .NET standard class library?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r yes it was created on .NET standard 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when adding a new .NET Standard class library to your a solution Visual Studio's intellisense will not pick up changes to code in your .NET Standard class library from reference projects. Restarting Visual Studio seem to resolve the issue.

---

In terms of your second question

> Do you know how I have to register the Interfece or beeing an mvvmcros
>   Project it's not necessary?

It is necessary. MvvmCross provides [options](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/Customizing-using-App-and-Setup#registering-platform-specific-business-objects-in-setupinitializefirstchance-and-setupinitializelastchance) inside of your `Setup.cs` class allowing you to register your platform specific implementation against an common interface defined in your core project.

- `InitializeFirstChance`
- `InitializeLastChance`

> For many objects the choice of when to initialize - first or last -
>   doesn’t matter. For others, the key choice is whether the service
>   needs to be available before or after the App is created and
>   initialized.

**Example**

```
protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ILocalFileHelperService, LocalFileHelperService >();
}
```